# file mutex for ruby wiithout passing a block

Tags: ruby, mutex

I want to set up a file based mutex as a general utility, i.e. I don't want to copy and paste the same code all over the place.  I just want to use presence of the file to mean lockedness.  If two processes hit this at the exact same time, will one win and one lose?  If not, how to do I ensure that one and only one process can create a file:

```
def lock what
    # return true on success, false on failure
    # failure means something has already claimed the mutex
    if File.exist? ("tmp/#{what}")
        return false
    else
        # create it
        file = File.open("tmp/#{what}", "w")
        file.close
        return true
    end
end
```

now to unlock, just delete it

```
def unlock what
    if File.exist("tmp/#{what}"
        File.delete("tmp/#{what}"
    end
end
```

The reason I don't want to use a block is so I can have a general purpose locking file mutex that works cross-process.

```
if lock("process a file")
    # proceed to do something mutexy
    # and unlock when done
    unlock("process a file")
end
```

Will this work?  If two processes hit lock at the exact same time, will one win and one lose?  If not, how do I ensure that one wins and one loses?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-i-flock

Comment: flock only works with a block, see my requirement in the post

Comment: No, it doesn't. What makes you think so?

Comment: Using a block won't stop you from sharing a file mutex across processes. You just need to put the critical code for each process into a separate flock block that locks on the same file. Basically what's being done [here](https://code-maven.com/run-only-one-instance-of-a-script)